# How to align with a certain view in a VStack?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to achieve the following layout:

[image: Expected Layout]

As you can see, `Foo` is aligned with `Bar` horizontally, and there's a vertical line at the bottom of `Foo`.

I haven't managed to do it, the best I can do is the following one:

[image: My Layout]

Here is the corresponding code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(spacing: 5) {
                Text("Foo")
                    .padding(.bottom, 0)
                getVerticalLine()
            }
            Text("Bar")
                .padding(10)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .background(.yellow)
        }
        
    }
    
    private func getVerticalLine() -> some View {
        return Color.gray
            .frame(width: 1, height: 30)
            .padding(.leading, 0)
    }

}
```

My question is: how to modify the code to achieve the expected layout?

P.S. In the end, I want to achieve something like this:

[image: Final Expectation]

Comment: Just do as simple as  `HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete code that you want. You need to use multiplier for constant so that it fits in all devices.

**CententView**

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            FooBarView(isLastOne: false)
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: -18, trailing: 0))
            FooBarView(isLastOne: false)
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: -18, trailing: 0))
            FooBarView(isLastOne: false)
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: -18, trailing: 0))
            FooBarView(isLastOne: true)
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
        }
    }
}
```

**FooBarView**

```
struct FooBarView: View {
    var isLastOne: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            HStack {
                VStack(spacing: 5) {
                    Text("Foo")
                        .padding(.bottom, 0)
                }
                Text("Bar")
                    .padding(10)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .background(.yellow)
            }
            if !isLastOne {
                getVerticalLine()
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: -5, leading: 12, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func getVerticalLine() -> some View {
        return Color.gray
            .frame(width: 1, height: 40)
            .padding(.leading, 0)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Each of your activities are a single `HStack`, with the time on the left. The line is just something that connects each row, not necessarily part of the row itself.

You can use a `ZStack` to show the gray line on the back and the rows on the front; a background on the first column will avoid overlapping the gray line.

The alignment is assured by giving the same frame width to the first column (time) and the vertical line.

Here's an example:

```
struct Example: View {
    
    struct Activity: Hashable, Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        let time: String
        let activity: String
    }
    
    let activities = [Activity(time: "10.00", activity: "Exercise"),
                      Activity(time: "11.00", activity: "Work"),
                      Activity(time: "12.00", activity: "Study"),
                      Activity(time: "13.00", activity: "Coding")]
    
    let firstColumnWidth = 80.0
    let spacingBetweenLines = 30.0
    let internalPadding = 10.0
    let lineHeight = 20.0

    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                getVerticalLine
                    .frame(width: firstColumnWidth)
                Spacer()
            }
            
            VStack(spacing: spacingBetweenLines) {
                ForEach(activities) { item in
                    HStack(spacing: 5) {
                        Text(item.time)
                            .frame(height: lineHeight)
                            .padding(internalPadding)
                            .frame(width: firstColumnWidth)
                            .background(.white)
                        Text(item.activity)
                            .frame(height: lineHeight)
                            .padding(internalPadding)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                            .background(.yellow)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    private var verticalLine: some View {
        let lineHeight = internalPadding * 2 + lineHeight + spacingBetweenLines
        return Color.gray
            .frame(width: 1, height: lineHeight * Double(activities.count - 1))
            .background(.green)
    }
}
```

[image]